# Rename column without breaking functions

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to rename a table column such that all references to that column in existing functions are automatically updated?

e.g. Doing this

```
ALTER TABLE public.person RENAME COLUMN name TO firstname;
```

would automatically change a reference like the following in any function:

```
return query 
    select * from person where name is null;
```

Comment: If renaming the column does not cascade, you could always add a computed column with the previous name.

Comment: If this was just a matter of one column, perhaps. But I'm loking at renaming ~800 columns where ~600 functions will be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since function bodies are just strings, there is no way to automatically change references to columns in function bodies when you rename a column.